# Why I can not call method of WebComponent?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I wonder why I cannot call a method defined in web-component if I attached this component via `.append` instead of using tag name inside the template. Below I am providing few examples. One is not working(throwing an error). I wonder why this first example is throwing this error.

### Example 1

```js
const templateB = document.createElement('template');
templateB.innerHTML = `
<h1>ComponentB</h1>
`

class ComponentB extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.append(templateB.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  hello() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}

customElements.define('component-b', ComponentB);

const templateA = document.createElement('template');
templateA.innerHTML = `
<div>
<component-b></component-b>
</div>
`;

class ComponentA extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.append(templateA.content.cloneNode(true));
    this.componentB = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('component-b');
    console.log(this.componentB instanceof ComponentB);
    this.componentB.hello();
  }

}

customElements.define('component-a', ComponentA);

document.body.append(new ComponentA());
```

In this example, I am creating a web-component inside my js file and then directly appending it to document. In this case, I am getting an error that `.hello` doesn't exist in my `ComponentB`. What's more, the reference to my `ComponentB` instance which I get using `.querySelector` is NOT an instance of `ComponentB`.

### Example 2

```js
const templateB = document.createElement('template');
templateB.innerHTML = `
<h1>ComponentB</h1>
`

class ComponentB extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.append(templateB.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  hello() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}

customElements.define('component-b', ComponentB);

const templateA = document.createElement('template');
templateA.innerHTML = `
<div>
<component-b></component-b>
</div>
`;

class ComponentA extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.append(templateA.content.cloneNode(true));
    this.componentB = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('component-b');
    console.log(this.componentB instanceof ComponentB);
    this.componentB.hello();
  }

}

customElements.define('component-a', ComponentA);
```

```html
<component-a></component-a>
```

In this example, I am adding a web-component directly to html file. In this case, I am NOT getting an error and the reference to my `ComponentB` instance which I get using `.querySelector` is an instance of `ComponentB`.

### Example 3

```js
const templateB = `
<h1>ComponentB</h1>
`;

class ComponentB extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = templateB;
  }

  hello() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}

customElements.define('component-b', ComponentB);

const templateA = `
<div>
<component-b></component-b>
</div>
`;

class ComponentA extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = templateA;
    this.componentB = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('component-b');
    console.log(this.componentB instanceof ComponentB);
    this.componentB.hello();
  }

}

customElements.define('component-a', ComponentA);

document.body.append(new ComponentA());
```

In this example, I am creating a web-component inside my js file and then directly appending it to document. In this case, I am NOT getting an error and the reference to my `ComponentB` instance which I get using `.querySelector` is an instance of `ComponentB`. The only one difference between **Example 1** and **Example 3** is that here I am using `.innerHTML` instead of deep cloned template.

From my point of view **Example 1** is correct and should work. Can anybody explain to me why i am mistaken and why it is not working? Maybe you can also provide a solution how I can use `<template>` + `.cloneNode` inside js files to be able to access methods of my web-components created in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple explanation:

`.innerHTML` is **synchronous**

Thus `<div><component-b></component-b></div>` is immediately parsed when Component-A is constructed.

`.append` ***with Templates*** is **A-synchronous**, it will create the HTML in Component A shadowDOM, but leaves the parsing to later

I cleaned up your code to only show the relevant parts, and added `console.log` to show **when** Component-B is constructed

You can play with  the `append/append/innerHTML` lines in Component A

(complex explanation) In depth video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Note: You should actually try and avoid `this.componentB.hello` style coding,
as it creates a **tight coupling between components**. Component A should work even if B doesn't exist yet. Yes, this requires more complex coding (Events, Promises, whatever). If you have tight-coupled components you should consider making them 1 component.

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('component-b', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      console.log("constructor B");
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = "<h1>ComponentB</h1>";
    }

    hello() {
      console.log('Hello');
    }
  });

  const templateA = document.createElement('template');
  templateA.innerHTML = `<div><component-b></component-b></div>`;

  customElements.define('component-a', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      console.log("constructor A");
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"})
      .append(templateA.content.cloneNode(true));
      //.append(document.createElement("component-b"));
      //.innerHTML = "<div><component-b></component-b></div>";
      this.componentB = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('component-b');
      console.assert(this.componentB.hello,"component B not defined yet");
    }
  });

  document.body.append(document.createElement("component-a"));
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but before I attach my template to shadowRoot I am parsing my template synchronously anyway. Look on the beginning first I am creating a template tag then I am calling `.innerHTML` on it, so this should trigger synchronous parsing of my template. This doesn't count? If yes, why?

Comment: What's more, I think this should NOT be parsed in `.append` because I already parsed this using `.innerHTML` before and now I am creating a deep copy of this template (which is already parsed) and attaching. I think there is no any additional parsing. Am I wrong?

Comment: ``cloneNode`` does the parsing. Your ``.createElement("template")`` has the same behavior as a  ``<template>`` tag in the DOM, the HTML is NOT parsed. That why they came up with the confusing ``.content.`` reference. Because otherwise it would be a regular DOM element on which ``.innerHTML`` does parse. So ``.innerHTML`` behaves different on ``<template>``

Comment: Ok, so why here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#shadowdom in NOTE they wrote you are getting any performance gain by using `<template>` if you trigger parsing anyway?  Is parsing of `.cloneNode` is faster than `.innerHTML` parsing?

P.S. If you have any articles with more complex explanation, I would be thankful.

Comment: cloneNode isn't faster than innerHTML; they (probably) call the same parse code.
You only get a template performance gain when you parse it once, and inject the result multiple times in the DOM.
Sorry, never found any good examples. Learned this by doing. Don't think documentation is correct, MDN also has incorrect code examples. Even Justin Fagnani (that Lit guy from Google) tells people ``template`` is an expensive placeholder: see his comment under https://dev.to/sroehrl/webcomponents-it-s-really-that-easy-96e

Comment: Hi @Danny'365CSI'Engelman reg your comment on tight coupling (this.componentB.hello style), philosophically speaking, what's the difference between say, element.focus() (or blur or other similar methods) and element.hello()? In my opinion, both are an intentionally designed means to provide the outside world the ability to alter the behavior of the element. Hence, instead of avoiding coupling, isn't it better to check for loading of the required components using `whenDefined` before using it? (as suggested in https://shoelace.style/getting-started/usage?id=waiting-for-components-to-load)

Comment: ``whenDefined`` IS coupling, a Web Component will not be created until another Web Component was created. And I do use ``whenDefined``, when required.

Comment: What I meant is create an array of promises for all web components needed using `whenDefined` at the start before loading the rest of the web app so that all components *are available* by the time they need to be used. It's difficult to give an example in this tiny space of comments. I'll try to create a separate question in that regard. Thanks

Comment: In other words, for native components, the browser ensures they are available before they are used by the web page. Similarly, for custom components, the app itself needs to ensure they are available at the start before they are used ..

Comment: Sure, not unlike the classic jQuery ``onload`` event. Choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/upgrade

I first noticed that example 1 worked OK if I just added a tiny setTimeout before trying to call the componentB method. With further fiddling I was able to get Example 1 to work mostly as-is, the only change being I called the method described in the documentation link above on the component B reference before trying to access any of its methods.

```
 customElements.upgrade(this.componentB);
```

I would try to explain but honestly, the nuances and exact timings of Web Component lifecycle hooks are still somewhat befuddling to me. It was obviously an issue of the component not being fully registered in the custom element registry when the first attempt to access its method is being made, I'm just not sure why the other 2 examples work as expected whereas the first example requires an explicit 'upgrading'.